# Excluding values from surf plot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Suppose we have a `surf` plot like this:

```
A = round(peaks,0);
surf(A)
```

Is there any way to modify the colormap so that it excludes all values in `A` that are equal to `0`, as if they were `NaN`?

Colouring `0`'s as white without affecting the rest of the colourmap would be another acceptable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned the solution: set all `0`s to `nan`:

```matlab
A = round(peaks, 0);
A(A==0)=nan;  % in-place logical mask on zero entries
surf(A)
% The same, but with a temporary variable, thus not modifying A
B = A;
B(B==0) = nan;
surf(B)
```

Results in (R2007a):

[image]

If you do not want to modify `A` or use a temporary variable, you'll need to "cut a hole" in your colour map

```matlab
A = round(peaks);

unique_vals = unique(A);  % Get the unique values
cmap = jet(numel(unique_vals));  % Set-up your colour map
zero_idx = find(unique_vals==0);  % find 0 index
cmap(zero_idx,:) = 1;  % all ones = white. Nan would make it black

surf(A, 'EdgeColor', 'none')
colormap(cmap)  % Use our colour map with hole
```

NB: the `'EdgeColor', 'none'` pair is used to remove the edges of each patch, such that you don't see a "grid" where the values are 0.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I but I would like to keep them as 0's, this is why I specified "as if they were NaN". Sorry if this was not clear and thanks for your time.

Comment: @Aristarchos So you want this visual plot, but with a "gap" in the colour bar? That'd result in ... this plot? What'd be the benefit of doing that? If you want to keep `A` unchanged, simply create `B = A;B(B==0)=nan` and plot that.

Comment: That is because I want to have my variable and my plot linked if possible.

Comment: @Aristarchos well, I've conjured up something that might suit your needs, but it sounds like you're falling prey to the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why is it paramount to have your plot and variable "linked"? Are you somehow interacting with the plot which changes the data itself?

Comment: Yes, I am using the plot to delete unwanted points from the variable, so turning 0s to NaNs and copying the data to a second variable would add some unnecessary steps to the process. I really appreciate your solution, thank you very much!